# Spring Transactions Propagation

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

JMS/Datasource are full-XA 2PC and are managed by the Weblogic JTA Transaction manager.

1. The message listener is not transactional annotated...(but it seems that is able to participate in transactions, maybe because of the definition of the JMS container?)
2. If any unchecked exception is thrown from ServiceB, the transaction gets rollbacked and the message is put back to the JMS queue?
3. The exception is the caught in serviceA, logged and the dao.update(res) is happening in a new transaction, so it will always executed, regardless of the result in ServiceB.
4. If dao.update(res) fails, everything will get roll-backed

Can somebody confirm the above? Is my logic correct or am I missing something?

Please for comments and suggestions.

```
public class MyMessageListener
@Autowired
private ServiceA serviceA;

//I am not declaring this as a transcational.
public void onMessage(Message m) {  
       serviceA.methodA(m); 
}

public class ServiceA {

 @Autowired
private ServiceB serviceB;

 @Autowired
private DAO dao;

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void methodA() {
    try{
        String res = ServiceB.methodB(m);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      log.(e); 
     }
    dao.update(res);
}


public class ServiceB {

@Autowired
private DAO dao;

@Transactional
public void methodB(String m)  {
    dao.read()
    callExtSystem() //this can throw unchecked exception
    dao.insert()
}

public class DAO {

   @Transactional
   public read() {}

   @Transactional
   public insert(){}

   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public update(){}
}

 <bean id="jmsContainer"   class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
<property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
<property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener"/>
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/> //Weblogic JTA Manager
<property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/> 
</bean>

<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
```

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: heh. I tested and it works. But im not sure of the solution..im a bit confused that why i am seeking for some answers and exlanations